# How to prevent Turtle from crossing the line in Turtle Python?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I want make maze in Turtle, but I don't know, how to prohibit to Turtle crossing walls (lines).

I tried

```
#imports
from turtle import *
player_1 = Turtle()

#walls (lines)
class Walls:
    goto(-100, 0)
    goto(100, 0)

#start position of player (turtle)
player_1.penup()
player_1.goto(0, 100)
player_1.rt(90)

#player (turtle) can't touch walls
def walls():
    if player_1 == Walls:
        player_1.bk(15)
```

**My next problem is how to make Turtle move when a key is pressed (still for maze)**

Here I tried:

```
def move():
    if wn.onkeypress('Up', 'w'):
        y = player_1.ycor
        player_1.sety(y + 15)

    if wn.onkeypress('Down', 's'):
        y = player_1.ycor
        player_1.sety(y - 15)

    if wn.onkeypress('Right', 'd'):
        x = player_1.xcor
        player_1.sety(x + 15)
        
    if wn.onkeypress('Left', 'a'):
        x = player_1.xcor
        player_1.sety(x - 15)
```

My full code:

```
from turtle import *
player_1 = Turtle()
wn = Screen()

class Walls:
    goto(-100, 0)
    goto(100, 0)

player_1.penup()
player_1.goto(0, 100)
player_1.rt(90)

def move():
    if wn.onkeypress('Up', 'w'):
        y = player_1.ycor
        player_1.sety(y + 15)

    if wn.onkeypress('Down', 's'):
        y = player_1.ycor
        player_1.sety(y - 15)

    if wn.onkeypress('Right', 'd'):
        x = player_1.xcor
        player_1.sety(x + 15)
        
    if wn.onkeypress('Left', 'a'):
        x = player_1.xcor
        player_1.sety(x - 15)

def walls():
    if player_1 == Walls:
        player_1.bk(15)

while True:
    move()
    walls()
```

Reason, why isn't maze, but only line, is, I don't want write full code of maze when I don't know if I can it.

Comment: Please ask one question per question and provide clarity about what you tried to do so solve it and where you're stuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **How to Move a Turtle**

---

You used the `onkeypress(fun, key=None)` Method incorrectly, the Method should contain the following:
**fun** – *a function with no arguments or None*
**key** – *a string: key (e.g. “a”) or key-symbol (e.g. “space”)*

So what you did wrong is that you used a string instead of the function, so It will of course error out *"Expected type '() -> Any', got 'str' instead "*. Moreover you forgot to add the `listen()` Method which *"Sets focus on TurtleScreen in order to collect key-events"*, basically without it the onkeypress Method will not work.

**The Corrected code:**

---

```
wn.listen()


def up():
    player_1.forward(15)
    
    
def down():
    player_1.backward(15)
    
    
def left():
    player_1.left(90)
    
    
def right():
    player_1.right(90)


def move():
    wn.onkeypress(up, "w")
    wn.onkeypress(down, "s")
    wn.onkeypress(left, "a")
    wn.onkeypress(right, "d")


move()


wn.exitonclick()
```

For more info on [listen()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.listen), [onkeypress()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onkeypress) Methods

---

Hopefully this helped!